# Retrieve marker position to fields to submit

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code from the Google API docs. It does exactly what I want except i need to be able to get to get latitude and longitude of the marker once its been placed.

In my site , i have enabled the option to be able to select a location on the map, but i need to somehow get the latitude and longitude information from the marker that the customer has set, specifically in hidden fields so that i could store them when data is posted `$_POST`.

The code I have now is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=jsdlkajslkdjaslkdja&sensor=false&language=ar&region=SAU">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var map;
var markersArray = [];

function initialize() {
  var haightAshbury = new google.maps.LatLng(26.1631, 50.2044188);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: haightAshbury,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
  map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

function addMarker(location) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map
  });
  markersArray.push(marker);
}

// Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
function clearOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }
}

// Shows any overlays currently in the array
function showOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}

// Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
function deleteOverlays() {
  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {
      markersArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markersArray.length = 0;
  }
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I mainly need help on the JS side of this.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, every time the user places a marker, you want to store its latitude and longitude and then when he/she finishes, send all the points via POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a markersArray-variable which contains all markers.

Loop over the array, you will get the lat/lng for each item by using
`item.getPosition().lat()` and `item.getPosition().lng()`

---

**`<edit>`**

Limiting to 1 marker is easy.
Change this line:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
```

into this:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(event) {
```

**`</edit>`**

Comment: how can I limit it to one marker only? I do not wish them to place more than one marker